# What bottom bracket tool is needed to install a miche evo max bb?

Tags: maintenance, installation

https://www.miche.it/en/products/strada/movimenti-centrali/evo-max.html

It is 16 notch. I can't find information on this anywhere and instructions didn't come with the BB. I have tried the hollowtech II tool and it doesn't fit. It've also tried the park bbt-59.2 with no luck.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure a park BBT-69.2, BBT-19.2, or BBT-9 would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the standard Shimano or Campagnolo external cup bottom bracket tool for this, which works with both ITA and BSC thread versions.

I believe Park BBT 69.2 is correct.

[image: Campagniolo Tool]

[image: Shimano Tool]

[image: Park Tool BBT 69.2]

Perhaps your tool is damaged if you're having problems. Or maybe your tool is the newer, smaller shimano type for the itty bitty newer Shimano bearing cups.

Comment: I also just received confirmation from Miche that the park BBT-69.2 and equivalents is correct.